Relationship between covariant derivative and metric tensor
In general relativity, the covariant derivative of the coordinate vector is a tensor, equal to $$x^{\mu}_{:\rho} = x^{\mu}_{,\rho} + \Gamma^{\mu}_{\rho\nu}x^{\nu},$$ is it meaningful to equate this tensor with the metric tensor? Does it make sense to consider an equation of the form $$x^{\mu}_{:\rho} = g^{\mu}_{\rho}$$ for example?
It would, for instance, entail $x^{\mu}_{:\rho\nu} = 0$ and $v^{\rho}x^{\mu}_{:\rho} = v^{\mu}$, do these relations contain any meaningful physical properties?

In GR $x^\mu$ are not the components of a vector; $dx^\mu$ are.

The components of the metric tensor with mixed indices are just equal to the Kroncker delta[1]:
$$ g^\mu{}_\nu = \delta^\mu{}_\nu $$
I emphasize the components part because they are not the same object. Regardless of index positions, the Kronecker delta is defined without reference to a coordinate system, while the components of the metric tensor change under a transformation of coordinates[2].
Your question simply becomes then whether there is some vector $v^\mu$ that satisfies:
$$v^{\mu}{}_{:\nu} = \delta^\mu{}_\nu = v^{\mu}{}_{,\nu} + \Gamma^{\mu}{}_{\nu\rho}v^{\rho}$$
Which simply means the conditions on $v^\mu$ you've written are:
\begin{align*}
 v^{\mu}{}_{,\mu} + \Gamma^{\mu}{}_{\mu\rho}v^{\rho} &= 4\\
 v^{\mu}{}_{,\nu} + \Gamma^{\mu}{}_{\nu\rho}v^{\rho} &= 0 & (\text{for } \mu\neq\nu)
\end{align*}
I don't see that this leads to anything physically interesting in particular, but perhaps someone can correct me on that account.

 Edit - taking $x^\mu$ to be coordinate functions 
When first writing this I was certain you were just using $x^\mu$ as a weird notation for a proper vector. I didn't realize you are actually referring to the coordinate functions that map points from the manifold $M$ via some open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, to the reals, $\mathbb{R}$:
$$ x^\mu: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$
As @Ghoster noted in the comments, these however do not form a vector. They are simply $n$ independent scalar fields. Now, taking the covariant derivative of a scalar field is equal to taking its partial derivative so, writing $x^{(\mu)}$ rather than $x^\mu$ to clarify the $\mu$'s are not components of a vector:
$$ x^{(\mu)}{}_{:\nu} = \frac{\partial x^\mu{}}{\partial x^\nu} = \delta^\mu{}_\nu = g^\mu{}_\nu $$
Which just means the equation you wrote is trivially correct, since by definition the $x^\mu$'s are independent of one another.
